# Site redirects to login page in Chrome but not IE?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, google-chrome

I am working on various bug fixes on a small website and one thing is really confusing me.

Is there an easy explanation as to why some pages will redirect to a login page *instead of* the actual destination... **but only while using Chrome?**

Example: This page is supposed to check input against our mailing list and either add the details or return a message saying they're already on the list. It **works fine in IE** (go figure) but when I try it in Chrome it redirects me to the account login page.

HTML:

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/Standard-no-menu.master" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="join-email.aspx.vb" Inherits="JoinEmail" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true" />
<style type="text/css"><!-- @import url("/update-details.css"); --></style>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js/JScript.js"> </script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">


function validateForm()
{
    if (aForgotPwd.style.display != null && aForgotPwd.style.display.toString() != "none") {
        var emailEle = document.getElementById("<%= txtEmail.ClientID %>");
        emailEle.focus();
        return false;
    }

     if(document.getElementById('<%= txtEmail.ClientID %>').value=="")
    {
        alert("Please enter a value in the field \"Email\".");
        document.getElementById('<%= txtEmail.ClientID %>').focus();
        return (false);
    }

    validemail=0;
    var checkStr = document.getElementById('<%= txtEmail.ClientID %>').value;
    for (i = 0; i < checkStr.length; i++)
    {
        if(checkStr.charAt(i)=="@")
            validemail |= 1;
        if(checkStr.charAt(i)==".")
            validemail |= 2;
    }
    if(validemail != 3)
    {
        alert("Please enter a valid email address.");
        document.getElementById('<%= txtEmail.ClientID %>').focus();
        return (false);
    }


    if(document.getElementById('<%= txtFirstName.ClientID %>').value=="")
    {
        alert("Please enter a value in the field \"First Name\".");
        document.getElementById('<%= txtFirstName.ClientID %>').focus();
        return (false);
    }

    if(document.getElementById('<%= txtLastName.ClientID %>').value=="")
    {
        alert("Please enter a value in the field \"Last Name\".");
        document.getElementById('<%= txtLastName.ClientID %>').focus();
        return (false);
    }





}    


</script>
<h1>Join Global PC Mailing List
    </h1>
<div class="update-message"><asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="Server"></asp:Label></div>

<asp:Panel ID="pnlCreateAccount" runat="server">


<div class="update-row">
<div class="update-mandatory">*</div>
<div class="update-label">Email Address:</div>
<div class="update-field"><asp:TextBox cssClass="textbox" ID="txtEmail"  MaxLength="255" width="350" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><b><a id="aForgotPwd" href="/forgotten-password.aspx" style="display:none">&nbsp;Forgot password?</a></b></div>
</div>
<div class="update-row">
<div class="update-mandatory">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="update-label">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="update-field">We will never give your email address to anyone. Read our <a runat="server" href="~/privacy.aspx">privacy policy</a></div>
</div>
<div class="update-row">
<div class="update-mandatory">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="update-label">Company Name:</div>
<div class="update-field"><asp:TextBox cssClass="textbox" name="txtAccountName" ID="txtAccountName" MaxLength="40" width="350" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="update-row">
<div class="update-mandatory">*</div>
<div class="update-label">First Name:</div>
<div class="update-field"><asp:TextBox cssClass="textbox" name="txtFirstName" ID="txtFirstName" MaxLength="255" width="350" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></div>
</div>
<div class="update-row">
<div class="update-mandatory">*</div>
<div class="update-label">Last Name:</div>
<div class="update-field"><asp:TextBox cssClass="textbox" name="txtLastName" ID="txtLastName" MaxLength="255" width="350" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></div>
</div>

<h1>Choose Your Email Subscriptions</h1>

<div class="update-row">
    <div style="float:left">
        <div class="update-mandatory">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="update-label">Subscribe to General Newsletters:</div>
        <div class="update-checkbox"><asp:CheckBox ID="chkGenernalNewsletters" runat="server"></asp:CheckBox></div>
    </div>
    </div>
<div class="update-row">
    <div class="update-mandatory">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="update-label">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="update-field">
        <div class="green-button">
            <asp:LinkButton ID="btnRegister" OnClientClick="return validateForm();" AlternateText="Join Up" Text="Join Up" runat="server" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    </asp:Panel>
</asp:Content>
```

VB.NET

```
Imports DataAccessLayer
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Net.Mail

Imports com.verticalresponse.api

Partial Class JoinEmail
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Dim c As GPCUser
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Master.Page.Title += " | Register"
        If TypeOf Session("Customer") Is GPCUser Then
            c = CType(Session("Customer"), GPCUser)
            'Response.Redirect("update-details.aspx")
        Else
            c = New GPCUser
        End If

        If c.AccountNo = 0 Or c.AccountNo = CInt(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("WebsiteAccount")) Then
        Else
            Response.Redirect("update-details.aspx")
            Exit Sub
        End If

        If Not Page.IsPostBack Then

            Dim dt As DataTable = Nothing
            dt = SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("dbConn"), "x_ww_spGetCustomer", Request("custID")).Tables(0)
            If Not dt Is Nothing Then
                If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                    Dim dr As DataRow = dt.Rows(0)
                    txtAccountName.Text = dr("AccountName")
                    txtFirstName.Text = dr("FirstName")
                    txtLastName.Text = dr("LastName")
                    txtEmail.Text = dr("Email")

                    If Request("custID") > 0 Then
                        Dim subscriptions As ContactSubscriptions = New ContactSubscriptions(Request("custID"))
                        ' chkComputerPromotions.Checked = subscriptions.IsComputerPromotions
                        'chkElectronicPromotions.Checked = subscriptions.IsElectronicPromotions
                        chkGenernalNewsletters.Checked = subscriptions.IsGenernalNewsletters
                    End If

                End If
            End If
        End If


    End Sub

    Protected Sub btnRegister_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnRegister.Click

        '          c.CreateCustomerDetails(txtAccountName.Text, txtFirstName.Text, txtLastName.Text, txtEmail.Text, txtAddress.Text, txtSuburb.Text, txtCityTown.Text, txtPostcode.Text, txtPhone.Text, txtMobile.Text, lstCountry.SelectedValue)
        '                c.GeneratedPassword = txtPassword.Text
        '                GPCUser.AddUpdateCustomer(c)
        '                ' Save the subscription details
        '               
        'If Request("custID") > 0 and Request("AccNO") > 0 Then
        Dim subscriptions As ContactSubscriptions = New ContactSubscriptions(Request("custID"))
        'subscriptions.IsComputerPromotions = chkComputerPromotions.Checked
        'subscriptions.IsElectronicPromotions = chkElectronicPromotions.Checked
        subscriptions.IsGenernalNewsletters = chkGenernalNewsletters.Checked
        subscriptions.Save()
        'End IF
        '                Session("Customer") = c

        'SendUpdateAccountEmailMessage(c.EmailCount)


        'ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.GetType(), "Thanks", "alert('Your Website PC account has been created. ');", False)

        If chkGenernalNewsletters.Checked = True Then

            Dim listID As Integer = 284662333
            Dim isMember As Boolean = False


            Dim newSession As New loginArgs()
            newSession.username = "Not Relevant"

            ' Your VerticalResponse username
            newSession.password = "Not Relevant"

            'Your VerticalResponse password
            ' objLA.impersonate_user = "subaccount@emailaddress.com"; // If accessing or acting as a subaccount, uncomment this and replace it with the applicable email address.
            newSession.session_duration_minutes = "120"

            Dim [date] As DateTime = DateTime.Now



            ' This is generated by creating a Service Reference that points to the VerticalResponse WSDL. 
            Dim VRUser As New VRAPI()



            ' Let's try to log in. The login call will return a session ID, which we will use in all subsequent calls.
            Dim sessionId As String = Nothing
            Try
                sessionId = VRUser.login(newSession)


            Catch ex As System.Exception
                lblMessage.Text = ex.ToString()
            End Try

            Dim getMember As New getListMemberByEmailAddressArgs()
            getMember.session_id = sessionId
            getMember.list_id = listID
            getMember.email_address = txtEmail.Text

            Try
                VRUser.getListMemberByEmailAddress(getMember)
                isMember = True

            Catch ex As System.Exception
                isMember = False
            End Try
            If (isMember = False) Then
                Dim nMember As New ListMember()
                nMember.list_id = listID


                Dim memberData As NVPair() = New NVPair(2) {}

                memberData(0) = New NVPair()
                memberData(0).name = "email_address"
                memberData(0).value = txtEmail.Text

                memberData(1) = New NVPair()
                memberData(1).name = "first_name"
                memberData(1).value = txtFirstName.Text

                memberData(2) = New NVPair()
                memberData(2).name = "last_name"
                memberData(2).value = txtLastName.Text

                nMember.member_data = memberData

                Dim objAL As New addListMemberArgs()

                objAL.list_member = nMember
                objAL.session_id = sessionId

                Try
                    VRUser.addListMember(objAL)

                Catch ex As System.Exception
                    txtEmail.Text = ex.ToString()
                End Try

            Else
                pnlCreateAccount.Visible = False
                lblMessage.Text = "You are already on our mailing list."
                Exit Sub
            End If
        End If
        pnlCreateAccount.Visible = False
        lblMessage.Text = "you have successfully subscribed to Website PC email database."

    End Sub


    <System.Web.Services.WebMethod()> _
    Public Shared Function ValidateEmail(email As String) As String
        Dim wbClient As WebClient = New WebClient()
        Dim strUrl As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("WebsiteURLFull") + "/ajax/check_email_address.aspx?Email=" + email
        Dim reqHTML As Byte()
        reqHTML = wbClient.DownloadData(strUrl)
        Dim objUTF8 As UTF8Encoding = New UTF8Encoding()
        Dim output As String = objUTF8.GetString(reqHTML)
        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(output) Then Return String.Empty
        Return output
    End Function

    Private Sub SendMessage(fromEmail As String, fromEmailName As String, _
       toEmails As String(), IsBodyHtml As Boolean, message As String, subject As String)
        Dim mail As MailMessage = New MailMessage
        mail.From = New MailAddress(fromEmail, fromEmailName)

        For Each toEmail As String In toEmails
            mail.To.Add(New MailAddress(toEmail))
        Next

        mail.Bcc.Add(fromEmail)
        mail.IsBodyHtml = IsBodyHtml
        mail.Subject = subject
        mail.Body = message
        Dim s As New SmtpClient(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("MailServer"))
        s.Send(mail)
    End Sub

    Private Sub SendUpdateAccountEmailMessage(emailCount As Integer)
        Dim subject As String = "ALERT : Website user subscribed to email database"
        Dim message As String
        message &= "Via page join-email" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
        message += "Account No: " & Request("custID") & vbCrLf
        message += "Email : " & txtEmail.Text & vbCrLf
        message += "Account Name : " & txtAccountName.Text & vbCrLf
        message += "First Name : " & txtFirstName.Text & vbCrLf
        message += "Last Name : " & txtLastName.Text & vbCrLf
        message += "Email : " & txtEmail.Text & vbCrLf
        message += "Subscribe to General Newsletters : " & chkGenernalNewsletters.Checked & vbCrLf
        'message += "Subscribe to Computer Promotions: : " & chkComputerPromotions.Checked & vbCrLf
        'message += "Subscribe to Electronic Promotions: : " & chkElectronicPromotions.Checked & vbCrLf

        message &= vbCrLf & vbCrLf
        message += "Regards" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "WebsitePC Admin Team"

        SendMessage(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("AccountDetailsUpdateEmail"), "Website PC", _
                                New String() {ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("AccountDetailsUpdateEmail")}, False, message, subject)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Have you actually logged in once when using chrome, or are you developing in IE and then switched to chrome for a quick check?

Comment: I mostly use Chrome and am constantly logging in and out. I have a full copy of the site which is "live" but at a different URL so customer's don't accidentally find it, and the same issue happens in both the public facing site and the test site. Both sites seem to work fine in IE and Firefox, my boss uses IE and checks things there (so he hasn't noticed anything screwy)

I've been brought in as a developer in the last month-ish and this is my first gig so some things seem a bit odd to me. But is it weird for this to only affect one browser?

Comment: If it's a server side problem, kind of. If it's a client side issue. No. That's the beauty of jquery it masks differences in how different browsers support  javascript. Since you're using javascript it seems likely that's where the issue is but tbh for all the code you've put up I don't see that any of it relates to your problem. Is it redirecting implicitly or explicitly i.e. from the web.config setup or via a call like: `sessionId = VRUser.login(newSession)`. You need to first identify when/where it is redirecting.. then move onto to why.

Comment: It seems to be the register button that does it, but on one of the other pages the same thing is cause by the search button. Could it be a problem with the Postback stage?

Comment: This is weird, I used my chrome browser on my laptop at home and browsed to the site and it works without any issues. But back on my workstation today, and the issue is still there? Something to do with my chrome browser?